# Como modificar el valor o vinculo de un atributo .href desde vba excel?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

En mi empresa comenzamos a utilizar Altiris de Symantec
En este momento estoy en la tarea de la carga masiva de inventarios de hardware.
La carga de información la realizo usando Excel - VBA.
Los formulados de carga de datos están en formato HTML y JavaScripts

En una parte de ese formulario existe un link

> Haga clic para seleccionar...

Código

```
<A id=Assoc_74c9ad4_ARAEC_LabelAssocList onclick="return document.getElementById('Assoc_74c9ad4_ARAEC_ImgBtnMod').click()" href="#">Haga clic para seleccionar...</A>
```

y necesito que el atributo .href tenga el siguiente valor

> Estación de trabajo

Código

```
<A id=Assoc_74c9ad4_ARAEC_LabelAssocList onclick="return document.getElementById('Assoc_74c9ad4_ARAEC_ImgBtnMod').click()"
 href="/Altiris/AssetContractCommon/Manager/EditCreateResource.aspx?itemGuid=289a262b-61c7-4d3f-9483-b5fd1c3778bb&amp;resourceGuid=289a262b-61c7-4d3f-9483-b5fd1c3778bb"
 target=_WinViewAssocRes>Estación de trabajo</A>
```

He usado el siguiente código en Excel VBA, si bien funciona pero cuando guardo no toma los cambios

```
Set AllHyperlinks = IE.Document.getElementById("Assoc_74c9ad4_ARAEC_LabelAssocList")
AllHyperlinks.SetAttribute "href", "/Altiris/AssetContractCommon/Manager/EditCreateResource.aspx?itemGuid=289a262b-61c7-4d3f-9483-b5fd1c3778bb&resourceGuid=289a262b-61c7-4d3f-9483-b5fd1c3778bb"

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents

Loop

 AllHyperlinks.innertext = "Estación de trabajo"
```

¿Alguna idea de como resolver este error?

Comment: Reformule la pregunta, espero que quede mas claro mi consulta

Comment: Bienvenido Rafael. Me parece que has omitido algunos detalles importantes, ¿estás usando VBA para crear un objeto de Internet Explorer y abrir el formulario en cuestión? Por otro lado,es posible que tarde que temprano te pidamos un [mcve].

Comment: Si con VBA creo un Objeto de IE, luego desde una planilla de Excel voy llenando datos tales como Numero de Serie, Modelo, Marca etc

Comment: Con respecto al ejemplo desconozco si es posible dado que se trata de una aplicación licenciada la cual corre en servidores privados, pero si se podría trabajar con una copia del formulario web localmente.

Comment: `Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim targetURL As String
Dim sh
Dim eachIE

targetURL = "http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.com/Altiris/AssetContractCommon/Manager/EditCreateResource.aspx?ResourceTypeGuid=493435f7-3b17-4c4c-b07f-c23e7ab7781f&defaultsItem=8a163ec6-5c54-42f8-93b6-40a5a638c9ed"
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate targetURL`

Comment: ¿Y leíste [mcve] ?